# Продублировать исключение

Tags: sql, postgresql, исключения

Здравствуйте!

Есть две функции А и В. Функция А вызывает В.

Сейчас когда В падает в исключение функция А глотает его и происходит попытка insert id = null.
Как сделать так, что бы пользователь видел сообщение ошибки?

Фрагмент функции А:

```
CREATE FUNCTION A(data character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
id integer;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
    id = В(data);
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
    RAISE exception  -- как получить сообщение исключения полученного в B?
   END; 
insert into table_A (fk_table_B)
values (id);
END;
$BODY$
```

Фрагмент функции В:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION B(data character varying)
    RETURNS integer as
    $BODY$
        BEGIN
        --опасный код
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        RAISE exception 'Сообщение которое должен увидеть пользователь';
        END;

    $BODY$
```

Comment: У вас в функции А точно не перехватываются исключения? Приведите код функции А

Comment: Привел код функции

Comment: Если в функции А в блоке обработок ошибок написать ` RAISE NOTICE SQLERRM` ? Блок А вообще перехватывает ошибку как `no_data_found` ?

Comment: Не  перехватывается. Даже когда в A перехватываю любые исключения (Exception when OTHERS )   id так и остается null и выполнение функции А продолжается.

Comment: А если запускать отдельно функцию B, то сообщение об ошибке вываливается?

Comment: Нет, не вываливается опцию STRICT не указал. Спасибо за наводку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теле функции B была ошибка. Исключение NO_DATA_FOUND не генерировалась. 
Было:

```
BEGIN
id_party = (SELECT id FROM "PARTY" WHERE "PARTY".number_party = _number_party);
return id_party;
 EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
RAISE exception 'Ошибка';
END;
```

Когда SELECT без использования опции STRICT target, не находит ничего он не генерирует исключение NO_DATA_FOUND или TOO_MANY_ROWS. Что бы получать эти исключения нужно переписать запрос:

```
BEGIN
SELECT id INTO STRICT id_party  FROM "PARTY" WHERE "PARTY".number_party = _number_party;
return id_party;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
RAISE exception 'Ошибка';
END;
```

Для вывода сообщения исключения в функции  А нужно указать:

```
BEGIN
id = В(data);
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
RAISE exception '%', SQLERRM;
END;
```